# Riemann curvature tensor in real universe

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature

The way Riemann Curvature tensors are usually introduced is as follows:
Take a vector v at point A, parallel transport it to B then to C then again back to A, the resulting vector v' will not point in the same direction as v if the space is curved. The Rieman Curvature outputs the difference vector u = v' - v.

While this definition provides a nice visualization for a familiar surface, it’s hard to visualise what's actually going on in real spacetime. Let we have to axes, R and T. Let, as our tangent vector we choose the 4 velocity vector of a particle falling in geodesic (or any other suitable real example, may be light velocity). Can you please explain how, in Schwartzchild spacetime this vector changes directions after parallel transport from A to B to C to A? I want to figure out what exactly is happening.

Comment: The geometric intuition for the curvature tensor is the same regardless of if you're in Minkowski, or Schwarzschild, or any other Lorentzian manifold: the difference in parallel transport around "infinitesimally small" loops ( up to second order). But actually explicitly computing the curvature, in say Schwarzschild, is almost always an annoying task. And calculating exactly and explicitly (in closed form) the effect of parallel tranaport along a given curve is next to impossible because it is obtained as the solution of a certain sytstem of ODEs.

Comment: Well, exact calculations are not required. I would like to have some visual intuitions on how vectors change directions after parallel transport in Schwartzchild spacetime - for a 4-velocity vector which would result in 3-velocity change.